# Convert date to datetime2(7) in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting

In my Table valued function, I have a variable of type date. I need to compare it (in a where clause) with the values of a column in a table, whose type is datetime2. Can anyone please help me with this, as the cast is not working for me.

This is my code:

```
select * 
from table1 
where [Date1] >= cast(@Todate as datetime2)
```

Here, `[Date1]` is a column in `table1` of type `datetime2` and `@Todate` is of type `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query.

```
select * 
from table1 
where [Date1] >= convert(datetime2, @Todate)
```

Comment: This didn't work... :( I don't want to convert it in where clause, as there are huge number of records. So, I have put a variable of type datetime2, and compare this with the [Date1] column.                                                                                                                                                 DECLARE @ToDtTm DATETIME2 = Convert(DATETIME2, @toDate)

Comment: I got the solution. The issue was that, the date part was getting converted to datetime2, but with time as 00:00:00. Then I did in the following way, and it worked.

select *
from Table1
where [Date1] >= DATEADD(MS,-1,CAST(DATEADD(DD,1,@toDate) AS datetime2))